# ionic v2 app [Service based] not working on android devices

Tags: ionic2

ionic v2 app [Service based] not working on android devices. however the same working in the browsers. without service page is open easily, once service called nothing happend on the android device. please advice.

Comment: I advise you to share relevant code and error messages you're receiving.

Comment: i have used the sample from https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-mobile-app-with-angular-2-and-ionic-2  [All working no error, I have created the built successfully. ] http://www.9lessons.info/2017/01/ionic-2-mobile-app-using-angular-2-and.html

Comment: If the page is in white on a cell phone, you need chech if have html tag wrong. sometimes occurs with me when not closing a tag or in an invalid location.

Comment: I have tried below steps and now working fine                                                $ionic platform remove android
$ionic hooks add 
$ionic platform android

Answer (score 0):

I have used below before creating build

```
$ionic platform remove android
$ionic hooks add 
$ionic platform android
$ionic build android
```